# some advice about how to start an startup services

Tags: startup, freelancing

I am fluent with vulnerability research, and penetration testing, and red team tactics, and I only hold OSCP .

I was thinking about on creating a website similar to company services , and giving services, using marketing to get customers, and maybe with the help of 2 extra people with similar skills to get the job done. is it possible to do this without a physical company with only a great website as starting project?

Comment: `Is it possible?`  Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You're not going to like my answer, but... probably not.**

See, the huge obstacle you're going to have to overcome isn't anything to do with *technical* skills - it has to do with marketing.  Think about it from a medium-to-large company's perspective.  You know data security is important - important enough to hire an outside consulting firm to pen-test your environment.  Are they going to hire three random people with minor credentials that have a company with no/little prior history?  Or are they going to hire a consultant firm with history in the field and a positive reputation?

Don't get me wrong - that's not an insurmountable obstacle.  But... look at your post's title.  Look at the first run-on sentence.  Actually read your second paragraph's first sentence *out loud*.  I'm not trying to be mean, but... you don't strike me as someone who excels at marketing and communication.

That's the thing I think you'll need to understand going in, if you decide to try to make a small info-sec business.  The weakness and obstacle you'll have to overcome has nothing to do with the technical side: it'll be networking and being able to sell.  Because it'll be a tough hill to climb.

Comment: +1, but OP you definitely need a company AND professional indemnity insurance because it greatly helps to insulate you from risk. Suppose you do a Pen-Test and report for BigCo and 6 weeks later they have a massive breach, resulting in data theft and huuuge fines from regulatory authorities. Guess who they're going to pin that on...?